# How change url adress with id on name in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a website on which each user has his own page and has such an address `mysite.com/id44`, also, each user can make a short name and I want that instead of a id, the address would be `mysite.com/username`. How can this be realized?

Comment: Without code, no one can help you here.

Comment: you can use @A.A Noman's suggestion you can write whatever you want you should just write algorithm in function like can get user with it's username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. With no code is complicated, but let's try something.

On your controller just say

```php
Route::get('user/{user:username}', 'UserController@show')->name('user.home.page')
```

This will search for the user using username as the key.

Check out this video on laracasts Jeffrey Way has explained it very well:

https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-7/episodes/4

Or

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#implicit-binding

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

For **Laravel 7+**:

as Samuel Bié said...

```
Route::get('user/{user:username}', 'UserController@show');
```

For **Laravel 6-**:
add a method in User Model

```
/**
 * Get the route key for the model.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use like that in your route

```
Route::get('/{user?}', 'UserControllerNameController@your_method_name');
```

Comment: I want instead of id, in the address bar there was a name

Comment: `user` is a optional parameter. It accepts `id` or `username` or `empty`. Then you have to decide to `user`, is it number or string